# go get -u fails for package with a go1 branch

Tags: go

I'm distributing a go package that requires a lot of generated files that I don't want to include in the `master` branch of my git repository.  I'd like people to be able to install my software with `go get`.  Since `go get` doesn't run `go generate`, my solution was to stick all of the generated files in a `go1` branch that is one commit beyond `master` but also includes all of the generated files.  I can also add a second fake parent commit to the `go1` branch so that whatever people fetch `go1` it's always a fast-forward merge.  I don't care how ugly the `go1` branch gets so long as `master` stays pristine.

This technique works great the first time.  Unfortunately, every subsequent invocation of `go get -u` fails for people, **even if the `go1` branch hasn't changed at all**, because `go get` is leaving the checked-out repository in a detached HEAD state instead of on the `go1` branch.  I can fix this myself by manually going deep into my gopath to run `git checkout go1`, which will create a local `go1` branch tracking `origin/go1`, but this is very annoying to have to instruct other people to do.  At that point I'm better off just fighting the gopath system and telling people build the software with a Makefile.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or what to tell people?  The one thing I really don't want to do is run `git symbolic-ref` to change `HEAD` on the server, because `master` really needs to be the default branch for all developers.  Anyway, changing `HEAD` on the server shouldn't be necessary since `go get` is the one choosing to fetch the `go1` branch, so why doesn't it create a local `go1` branch that pulls from `origin/go1`?

Comment: Why don't you want to include the generated files in master? Maybe it's a matter of organising them so they fit in nicely? If you ensure that you commit all generated files (and only generated files) in one commit every time you generate them, your Git history should be easy to browse through. If you expect users of the master branch to run `go generate`, you risk them having different source code from what you have generated and tested.

Comment: The generation is deterministic, so no danger of users having different code.  For this particular project, the generated files are large and unnecessary to distribute and make merges extremely painful, as essentially every merge would have a conflict.

Comment: Apologies, I'm going off-topic since using a `go1` branch doesn't feel like the right thing to do here (i may be mistaken). I'd like to suggest a modified `git flow` model. If you ensure that all feature branches use `develop` as the base branch, and that branch must not contain generated code, you could cut releases off that branch, merge to `master` and generate the code there before tagging it as a release. Users would then get the generated code and you wouldn't have merge conflicts, and developers would know that they should work on `develop`.

Comment: How is your suggestion any better than/different from making `HEAD` point to `go1`?

Comment: You seem to have devised a very elaborate solution to a non-problem. Or at least, to a problem you haven't explained. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Admittedly there isn't much different practically. OTOH, the `go1` branch is supposed to be the branch that's compatible with Go 1.*, but it seems to [no longer be the preferred method for that](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5779#issuecomment-66081650). Maybe there won't be a `go2` in the future. That's why it feels wrong to me. Using `master` as the branch to tag releases on is so common that it feels like one less deviation from convention to worry about.

Comment: The obvious difference being that it's a more well known workflow, and it works with `go get`.

Comment: @Flimzy The problem is achieving 3 things simultaneously:  1) `go get -u` works without the need for every user to mess with stuff deep in their gopath, 2) a default repo clone gets you the base branch you should develop from, and 3) independent pull requests can be cleanly merged without gratuitous conflicts in generated files.  I can only figure out how to get two out of these three simultaneously.  I think most of these comments are arguing that either #2 or #3 is not important.  In my setup, it just so happens #1 is the least important, but it would still be nice if possible.

Comment: @user3188445: Thanks for clarifying the problem. My proposed solution, and the one I've seen used in countless projects, is to drop your third requirement. Conflict resolution of generated files is super easy (just re-generate the files), so not really worth trying to work around.

Comment: @Flimzy Our flow differentiates between merges that apply cleanly and those that have conflicts.  So even though the conflicts are easy to resolve, we still want to know if a pull request can apply cleanly or not, and depending on how you look at it, including generated files either obscures this information or ensures the answer is always "not."

Comment: If it's a matter of tooling, it should be easy to exclude generated files from an automated test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is just a bug in cmd/go.  Here's a link to the issue:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27526

If this bug gets fixed in 1.12, then what I want to do will just work.